# Ranger is not installing in Kerberos Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, ambari, apache-ranger

I have installed the Kerberos Hadoop cluster from Ambari V2.7.3 and HDP 3.1.1 Now I am installing Apache ranger from Ambari In the same Hadoop cluster. But I am facing below errors while installing Ranger.

```
RuntimeError: Failed to execute command '/usr/bin/apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef --allow-unauthenticated --assume-yes install ranger-3-1-0-0-78-admin', exited with code '100', message: 'E: Failed to fetch http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/ubuntu16/3.x/updates/3.1.0.0/pool/main/r/ranger/ranger-3-1-0-0-78-admin_1.2.0.3.1.0.0-78_all.deb  403  Forbidden



E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Here first we need to install ranger Then only we need to install Kerberos?

Comment: You asked the same question 3 times, do you really think that makes a difference?

Comment: Try by disabling firewall (systemctl stop firewalld.service)